# remove required from input fields that are in hidden divs

Tags: jquery, forms, html, input, required

I have one form and couple of divs with bunch of input fields, and one select field that shows one div and hide all others. In those input field I have html5 required tag. 
I would like to remove required tag from all input fields that are in hidden divs.
How can I do that?
Here is my js for show/hiding divs depending on my select options:

```
    <script>
function changeGroup(e) {
    /*
        1 - Remove all group classes
        2 - Add the currently selected group class
    */
    $("#main")
        .removeClass(allGroups)
        .addClass($("option:selected", e.target).val())     
}

/* 
    1 - Bind changeGroup function to "change" event
    2 - Fetch all group from the select field 
*/
var allGroups = $("select")
    .change(changeGroup)
    .find("option")
        .map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        })
        .get()
        .join(' ');


</script>
```

Thank you for help...
Dorijan

Answer (score 11):

Would use `prop()` method since `required` is a property. Once you remove the property then if user toggles so the become visible again  have no current mechanism to track where they got removed.

For this reason I suggest you add a class `required`to all the inputs that have `required` property.

```
$('.required').prop('required', function(){
   return  $(this).is(':visible');
});
```

This will loop over all of the class `required` and adjust property based on visibility

Comment: There is a much better feature to solve the problem: fieldset:disabled. see: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/K8EPm/

Comment: how does fieldset:disabled replace any of the validation functionality of :required?

Comment: @davidtallon anything within a disabled fieldset is disabled...disabled controls don't submit therefore can't be required

Answer (score 2):

To remove 'required' attribute from group of elements or all input child of div using jQuery you can try this:

```
$("#hiddenDiv :input").prop('required',null);
```